# Is it possible two have two static routes that are each going to a different remote site from the host site and have back up routes too?

Tags: routing

Is it possible to use static routes to communicate point to point where the host talks to two different networks simultaneously? The remote sites do not talk to each other, just host to remote and host to remote.

I am using Cisco 2921 routers. Also, at each site there is a back up communication line if the primary fails. So I would want to have that set up too as back up static routes for each remote site. Example is host IP 192.168.5.1 to remote IP 192.168.6.1 and the same host 192.168.5.1 to the other remote 192.168.7.1. Will this be a problem if I don't want one as a priority over the other?

Comment: Do you have a little more information on the type of access these devices need? It could mean the difference between a NAT, port forwarding, and a VPN.

Comment: A network diagram with routers, hosts, and broadcast-domain clouds would be useful, I think.

Comment: It is one computer at one site that needs to talk to one computer at one site and another computer at another site.  They are communicating over a dedicated T1.